# Issue in passing numbers with leading zero in the csv from java code

Tags: java, jenkins

I am appending a tab before I am passing a value to csv like

```
"\t"+"08053"
```

This is working fine on my mac and i can see 08053 in my csv file. However the same is not working when I am running the script on Jenkins which run on a linux environment. I can see only 8053 in the csv file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somehow the title does not fit the description in the question.

Comment: What does this question have to do with leading zeros in a csv?